# how to reverse the numbers in this pattern

Tags: java

I wanna make a pattern like this this pattern is similar to flyords triangle but the alternate rows are in reverse order i tried something but couldn't get the expected output

```
1
3*2
4*5*6
10*9*8*7
11*12*13*14*15
```

I tried this stuff ,

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int count=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                if(i>j) {
                    System.out.print(count + "*");
                    count++;
                }else {
                    System.out.print(count);count++;
                }
            }System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

the result i got is,

```
1
2*3
4*5*6
7*8*9*10
11*12*13*14*15
```

how to reverse alternate rows :(

Comment: Your code is Java, so please do not tag C or C++ as this code will compile in neither

Comment: You can count backward in your for loop with  --count, and  set count accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start number that would normally be last in that row for every even row. That is your starting number will be `i-1` larger that it would normally be, and instead of `count++` you `count--`.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    int count=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        if (i%2 == 0)
        {
            count += i-1; // there are i numbers on this row, highest is (i-1) larger than lowest
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                if(i>j) {
                    System.out.print(count + "*");
                    count--;
                }else {
                    System.out.print(count);
                }
            }System.out.println();
            count += i // count was lowest number on current row. Increase it to lowest number on next row.
        }
        else 
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                if(i>j) {
                    System.out.print(count + "*");
                    count++;
                }else {
                    System.out.print(count);count++;
                }
            }System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can determine how much to add using the trinary operator on the oddness of the line number and set the correct starting value of that line inside the definition of your for loop:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int currentNumber = 0;
    for (int line = 1; line <= 5; currentNumber += (line++))
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= line; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(currentNumber + ((line % 2 == 1) ? i : line + 1 - i));
            if (i < line)
                System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int count = 1;
        int plus = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            plus = i - 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    if (i > j) {
                        System.out.print(count + plus + "*");
                        plus-=2;
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(count+plus);
                        count++;
                    }

                } else {
                    if (i > j) {
                        System.out.print(count + "*");
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(count);
                        count++;
                    }
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```